# Why are you a plonker?

Tags: idioms, british-english, slang, colloquialisms

The idiom, *plonk (something/someone) down* means

> - to slap something down; to plop something down
> - to sit or lie down on something in a careless or noisy way
> - to leave someone somewhere to do this; *Dave plonked the kids in front of the TV and disappeared upstairs.*
> - to put something down heavily and without taking care:
>     *Just plonk the shopping (down) on the table, and come and have a cup of tea*.
>     *Come in and plonk yourselves (down)* (= sit down) *anywhere you like*.

From these various definitions I can surmise why cheap wine is often called *plonk*, it's the sound of the bottle slapping down heavily on the table.

But how did we get from that to “**a plonker**” which basically means a silly or stupid person.

As in

> "Why did you do that, you plonker?"

[image: Rodney from Fools and Horses]
<sub>Nicholas Lyndhurst who played Rodney Trotter in *Only Fools and Horses*</sub>

References: [FD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/plonk); [*plonker*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/plonker) "Sir David Jason says an American remake of Only Fools And Horses won't work as there's no word over there for plonker." [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/plonker?q=plonker); [*plonk*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/plonk_1?q=plonk)

Comment: I can't answer definitively, but I'd guess it's because _plonk_ could be described as a "dull sound," so someone thought it could also be applied to a dull person. From NOAD: **dull** (*adj.*) • (of sound) not clear; muffled • (of a person) slow to understand; stupid.

Comment: I think that [ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/plonker) might answer this. Specifically, sense 2. It's a playful insult.

Comment: o_0 Who knew?! Well, I never

Comment: I think I prefer to use *plonker* as suggested by @J.R. It's definitely less rude! :)

Comment: Sadly, though, I think the theory offered by @Andrew is the more likely one. It certainly casts a new light on the title of your question! As might be surmised by my clueless guess, I've not heard that word use in that way over on this side of the pond, though we have plenty of substitutes.

Comment: @J.R. No, I'm not yet convinced Andrew et al have nailed it. There are now two or three separate theories. You don't have "plonker" in the US? Start a trend.

Comment: I've used "plunk" in conversation, but haven't heard plonk before.  Plunk has also taken on the meaning of "to be intentionally or strategically hit with a baseball by the pitcher while batting" in american baseball games.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hit_by_pitch#Tactical_use
In that case, a "plunker" would be a pitcher with a propensity to intentionally hit batters while pitchingy.  It sounds like it doesn't carry the same general sense of "plonker" that was described above.
There is apparently a website dedicated to tracking plunks in Major League Baseball:
http://www.plunkeveryone.com/

Comment: Cheap wine is called *plonk* due to WWI French-to-English transformation of *vin blanc* to *plonk*.  See eg [1](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-plo1.htm), [2](http://www.thekitchn.com/good-question-17-46229), [3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plonk_%28wine%29)

Comment: @jwpat7 What about the verb, to plonk? Does that postdate, the noun, plonk?

Comment: Could just be that the person is being described as careless or lazy, that they just "plonk" stuff down on the floor, or they just "plonk" down on the couch and watch TV.

Comment: @AJMansfield sounds plausible to me. I thought the noun and the verb were more closely related.

Comment: @Mari-LouA this is highly dialect-dependant, though.  What "plonker" means where you live could be quite different from what it means in different regions.

Comment: @AJMansfield  No, the meaning of plonker IS a stupid, silly, slow-witted man  but not always, I've been called a plonker myself at times! (and I 'm a woman. I think that statement needed clarification just in case...)

Comment: A plonker would suggest that you are a dick.

Comment: Well @Noah until yesterday I didn't know that. But I think its the meaning has muted since then (see dictionary definitions) and now it *is* more commonly used to say someone is foolish, a bit of an idiot. I was trying to connect the dots :"to plonk" (to hit something hard) "plonk" (cheap wine) and "plonker". But the etymology of the word is fascinating, don't you think?

Comment: Plonking, and with no reference to [Stephen Potter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_Potter)'s *Gamesmanship* (etc.) books?!  ... Well, I think he first used the term in [Lifemanship](http://tinyurl.com/kbvu88m), but still the fact remains that he added an important meaning to the 'word'.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The *Urban Dictionary* suggests *plonker* is a person [habitually drunk on cheap wine](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=plonker)
, (*plonk*) and hence someone who is foolish or useless.

I don't think that's right. I believe *plonker* in this context is a slang term for *[penis](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/plonker)* (chiefly used in the term *pull someone's plonker*, attempt a mild deception). Slang terms for penis are routinely used as terms of abuse, and that is why *plonker* is used for this purpose.

**Edit** I've just had a chance to look in Green's *Dictionary of Slang*. He has three entries for *plonker*:-

> Anything large or substantial (figurative usage of standard English *plonk*, to hit or strike with a plonking noise). Earliest reference 1861.
>
> Also *plonk*, the penis, earliest reference c1920 in the phrase *pull one's plonker*
>
> Also *plonk*, a general term of abuse, widely popularized by the BBC TV Series *Only Fools and Horses*, earliest reference 1959.

Comment: I had no idea! I've always said it innocently to my friends, almost as an endearment. Arghh! :)

Comment: Oh, @Mari-LouA, what they must think of you! Lol!

Comment: @Mari-LouA In my experience it always has been a very mild rebuke.

Comment: Yes the penis suggestion is correct.

Comment: No doubt whatsoever. Here's Jasper Carrott (UK standup comic) in 1979... [I put my hands up to protect myself, but all she does is pull down my zip and **get my plonker out!** It's that sort of very embarrassing situation. I mean, what do you do? I didn't want to appear a spoilsport and not be one of the lads or anything...](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22zip+and+get+my+plonker%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). It was an "acceptable" euphemism back in the days when you couldn't use *dick, prick, cock, chopper,* etc. on British live TV.

Comment: ...and from UK satirical magazine Private Eye in 1973... [The Pellers wore it in the old days. **Protects your plonker!**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22the+pellers+wore+it%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) And no - I don't know who the "Pellers" were.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Any links which might back up Jon Hanna's reference to condoms? And you should post the Jasper Carrott link as an answer, which might mean that Del Boy really was the creator of this usage, plonker meaning someone very dim-witted i.e Rodney.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: Del Boy definitely *wasn't* the "creator" of the usage.  John Sullivan (the scriptwriter) was busy on other projects [until late 1980](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Only_Fools_and_Horses). Carrott was broadcasting it at least a year before *Only Fools And Horses* and Private Eye were printing it *eight* years before with the relevant meaning. I've never heard *plonker = condom*, but the word has had many meanings of limited currency over the decades - it was a specific type of kids' marble in Scotland in the 50s, and a weaving tool long before that, for example.

Comment: But before the TV series was it a common way to refer to someone who was "slow" and not very bright? When did plonker, euphenism for penis, change into "idiot"? I've read that the show was responsible for many different catch phrases such as "jumbly" and "twonk"! It might be possible that's "plonker" continues to exist thanks to the show. (I'm playing devil's advocate here)

Comment: Really? 1861 is the earliest citation of "plonk" as in to hit something loudly in a plonking noise? Have you seen @SvenYargs answer? By the way the programme is *Only* Fools and Horses, you did a typo.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, _plonker_ in the sense of something large or substantial, in C.C.Robinson's _Dialect of Leeds_, 1861: "A _plonker_ is an article having extraordinary substance. A piece of woven material unusually thick is '_a plonker_'". I haven't been able to run down a date for the standard English meaning (_plonk_ something down).

Answer (score 11):

The origin of *plonker* is from *plonk* + *-er*<sup>1</sup>, where *plonk* is a verb<sup>2</sup> meaning

> To hit or strike [something] with a heavy thud

Although this meaning is now rare.

*Plonker* itself has a few meanings, including "something large and substantial of its kind", "penis" and "a foolish, inept, or contemptible person"<sup>1</sup>.

The first use of *plonker* to mean "a foolish, inept, or contemptible person" is attested in the OED to be an episode of Only Fools and Horses (in 1981)<sup>1</sup>. I would imagine that this use is actually related to the use of *plonk* to mean "To set or drop (a thing) in position heavily or clumsily"<sup>2</sup> as inept people are wont to.

However, as Brian Hooper points out, *plonker* can mean penis<sup>1</sup>. The OED gives this example usage:

> **to pull one's plonker** : to masturbate

This seems just as likely the origin, for the reasons Brian mentions, although not before [the BBC watershed](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/specials/1738_respect/page9.shtml).

1. "plonker, n.". OED Online. June 2013. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/145905?redirectedFrom=plonker (accessed July 26, 2013).
2. "plonk, v.". OED Online. June 2013. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/145903 (accessed July 26, 2013).

Comment: I can't open the links (presumably I have to be a member) but your explanation is good.

Comment: Can you put some of the text of those links here? I have no idea what the OED entry is saying.

Comment: @Mitch They're just references. What do you need clearing up?

Comment: I can't visit those sites. I don't know what they say.

Comment: Right, @Mitch, I know that. but I'm not just going to rip off their copy right, so what am I not explaining well enough?

Comment: @MattЭллен Altho' not disputing your 'quotes' from the OED, I'm a little puzzled because the [ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/plonker?view=uk) states "Origin: **mid 19th century** (as a dialect word meaning 'something large of its kind'): from the verb plonk + -er". OTOH, it's entry for [plonk](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/plonk) contradicts that(!): "Origin: **late 19th century** (originally dialect): imitative; compare with plunk".

Comment: The [`PL-` assonance](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/pl.pdf) in English has the sense of 'Two Dimensional Thick/Contact' which is exactly right for the plopdown meaning of _plonk_. I've also heard it used as a verb for someone who fools someone else in jest; _Aw, he's just plonking you_. And also for locally-made alcohols of various low grades. As for the penis affiliation, some people believe you can't have too many words for drunk, vomit, stupid behavior, and anything associated with penises. So practically anything even mildly disreputable gets tagged sooner or later.

Comment: Isn't there a question on EL&U about how the sounds of combined letters could lead one to have an intuition on its meaning? As CRisp, CRack, CRash... Maybe there's a 'French' word that sounds like "plonk" and that might explain why it's used for men's penises? ( I don't speak French)

Comment: @TrevorD — Yes, the OED says plonker comes from "Apparently < plonk v. (although this is first attested slightly later)". So your guess is as good as mine.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: yes. search for phonosemantics. Of which John Lawler is a scholar.

Comment: Your section on 'plonker' meaning 'penis' says nothing of substantive. Please paraphrase the OED using many more content words if a short quote doesn't suffice. ELU should be self-contained (I'm not doing this out of principle...I really don't know/have ever heard 'plonk' being used for 'penis' so I'd like to see the expected meaning and example.

Comment: @Mitch See my linked entries for the ODO in a comment above.

Comment: Thanks @TrevorD, that helps, but is 1) presumably not the same as the OED entries and 2) the answer still needs to be amended to have _some_ of the semantic content of the OED entries.

Comment: @Mitch it has lots of the what the OED has. That's that the 1s and 2s are.

Comment: @MattЭллен: doesn't the OED have quotes too?

Comment: @Mitch: The word *plonker* has had many different meaning at different times and [localised] places. In the UK in the 70s the *penis* sense wasn't well known, so whereas the BBC couldn't be having people say *"Don't be such a prick!"* on primetime TV, they could get away with *plonker* (and just let everyone assume the word meant *idiot*, which in context it effectively did). I recall that around the same time they tried to slip in *twat/twot* in much the same way. But they had to bury that one 'cos it turned out too many people already knew it and complained vociferously!

Comment: So, upper-class twit is ok, upper-class twot isn't. Good to know these things.

Answer (score 8):

My understanding of the definition of 'plonker' is quite different! It stems from the very popular UK television series of the 1980s called Only Fools And Horses, set in London's Peckham.

Writer John Sullivan used a number of sound-alike words to substitute for non-permissible rude ones and 'plonker' was one of these. Use your imagination for what he meant when lead character, Del-Boy said to his brother 'don't be a plonker, Rodney!'

Comment: another who upholds the genitalia theory.

Comment: Hate to be obtuse, but no I don't have the imagination, especially not in BrE. Can you give the explicit terms? Put them in aurora that way you're only referring to rude things instead of being rude.

Comment: Well, obtuse or not, the word that I think all of us Brits would take it to mean would be 'wanker' or 'tosser.' There, I've said it.

Comment: "Plonker" wasn't made up by John Sullivan. It predates Only Fools and Horses.

Comment: @Mitch, don’t mean to derail, but is “put them in aurora” a way of saying “put them in quotes”? I’ve never seen this expression before (and can’t find it in any dictionaries), so I’m curious.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: iPhone spell suggest error. But yes, good call, by 'aurora' I meant 'quotes'.

Comment: AmE has neither wankers nor tossers.  We do have jerk-offs.

Answer (score 5):

*Plonker* used to be slang for condoms, and sometimes for penises.

There are several other possibilities, but the context makes this one seem more than plausible because it was heavily used in BBC sit-coms and they were fond of using substitute swearwords that were obscure, which those senses of *plonker* had become. Other examples would include *naff* (probably, but not certainly from Polari slang meaning "heterosexual") and *smeg* (probably, but not certainly, from *smegma*).

The deliberate obtuseness as to where the word came from allows the writers to get away with it. (In the case of *naff* the meaning wouldn't be much of a problem, but the source would itself have been a bit scandalous in those days).

More modern examples would be the heavy use of *feck* on "Father Ted"; which makes perfect sense in the context as it's a milder form of *fuck* in Ireland, but largely unknown in the UK, and the fondness of American writers for having British characters say *bollocks* and *wanker*, allowing them to use words of a level of offensive force above what American prime-time allows because the words aren't much used there, but acceptable for broadcast in the UK because of more lenient rules.

Comment: Could you provide the time setting when it used to mean *condoms*

Comment: Around the middle 20th C. WWII and there-abouts.

Comment: Can you provide any links or references to say that *plonker* was around in the 1940s/50s? (I don't think I'll ever say that word again without blushing.)

Comment: I can't think of any of the top of my head other than the movie "Wish You Were Here" (the 1987 one with Emily Lloyd, not the more recent one) using it as such.

Answer (score 4):

There are some references on the web to plonk as the lowest ranking person in the Royal Air Force (RAF), which apparently is an Aircraftman 2nd class, sometimes referred to as an [AC plonk](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Transwiki%3aRAF_Speak), and another for plonk as a [slang term for mud](http://www.englishforums.com/English/OriginEarliestUsagePlonkerRodney-Plonker/hmhwv/post.htm), coined in the trenches during the Great War, so its origins could lie in the notion of a person of lowest rank or status, or someone down in the mud.

Comment: That's very interesting but could you provide a link from somewhere, please?

Comment: Links added. The reference to mud, was given in an answer by John Dean on page 2, who was quoting the New Statesman.

Answer (score 2):

I have heard *plonk* used by speakers in the United States to refer to cheap wine (the definition that Merriam-Webster's gives), but not in any other way. Chapman & Kipfer, *Dictionary of American Slang*, Third Edition (1995), however, gives two definitions:

> **plonk** **1 n** *British fr Australian by 1930* Inferior wine; cheap wine **2 n** *by 1960s* A boring or obnoxious person =PILL.

The second definition would seem to be a candidate for the meaning of *plonker*, except that (1) the usage is not widespread in the United States, to my knowledge, and (2) the example in the original posting appears to be British, anyway.

Partridge, *A Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English*, Fifth Edition (1961) gives two early meanings of *plonk* as a noun:

> **plonk.** Mud, esp. that of no-man's land: military 1916–18. (Hence, over the plonk, 'over the top'.) ... 2. Pinky, cheap port, sold by the quart: Australian: from ca. 1926.

and two of plonker:

> **plonker.** A (cannon) shell: Australian soldiers': 1939+ ... 2. Penis: low: since ca. 1917.

Partridge also notes that *plonk* was used as a verb in World War I with the meaning "to shell." By his reckoning, the chronological order of occurrence of the different meanings of *plonk* and *plonker* is "to shell" (1915), "mud" (1916); "penis" (ca. 1917), "cheap wine" (ca. 1926)," "cannon shell" (1939).

Comment: So practically, plonk, did not start off as a light-hearted rebuke but first appeared with the technological advancements in WWI military warfare. I found this in wikipedia which *fuses* the planting or explosions of bombs in mud: "the wire-cutting No. 106 fuze was developed, specifically designed to explode on contact with barbed wire, or the ground before the shell buried itself in mud, and equally effective as an anti-personnel weapon "

Comment: And this image of a WWI [bomb shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:18-pounder_HE_round_with_No_106_fuze.jpg) **explains why** plonk and plonker came to mean "something large and substantial of its kind" and "penis".

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the meaning of plonk as to plop something down: in American usage the word here is plunk, not plonk ("He plunked the groceries down on the counter.") Plonk refers to cheap wine. (Random House Dictionary, 2013).